# SUM on a column from subquery in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Im trying to take Total transaction count from a table`between the given date on oracle database.I wrote a subquery to group unique transactions and when i try to sum across the columns in subquery i get an error ORA-00904: ColumnName : invalid identifier. Im new to oracle but this same used to work for me in sql server.

Here is my query.

```
select sum(Tots),sum(CRIR),sum(RT),sum(Succes) from( 

select  ds.LOAN_ID,ds.CUST_ID,TO_CHAR(ds.SENT_DT_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "Dates", count(*) "Tots", 
  SUM(DECODE (ds.STATUS, 'CR', 1,'IR',1,0)) "CRIR",
  SUM(DECODE (ds.STATUS, 'R', 1,'T',1,0)) "RT",
  SUM(DECODE (ds.STATUS, 'S', 1, 0)) "Succes"
  FROM DATA_STRING ds
  WHERE TRUNC(ds.SENT_DT_TIME) BETWEEN to_date('2016-10-04','yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2016-10-07','yyyy-mm-dd')
  Group by ds.LOAN_ID,ds.CUST_ID,TO_CHAR(ds.SENT_DT_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```

Comment: What is the full error message? It should point you to the line and position of the offending identifier, does that help? (Share that info here if you need more help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would be much more simply written as:

```
select count(*),
       sum(case when status in ('CR', 'IR') then 1 else 0 end) as CRIR, 
       sum(case when status in ('R', 'T') then 1 else 0 end) as RT, 
       sum(case when status in ('S') then 1 else 0 end) as Succes
from data_string ds
where ds.sent_dt_time >= date '2016-10-04' and
      ds.sent_dt_time < date '2016-10-08';
```

Notes:

- Two levels of aggregation is not needed for what you want to do.
- Use `case` instead of `decode()`, because `case` is standard SQL.  It is also simpler to incorporate logic such as `in`.
- Oracle supports the `date` keyword, which can be followed by a standard date.
- Almost exactly the same query works in SQL Server (minus the `date` keyword).

Comment: I want to do group by to group all the unique transactions on a day

Comment: @Raju . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  A double aggregation is not necessary.  If you have *another* question, then ask it as *another* question.  If you modify this one, it could invalidate this answer and hence attract downvotes.

Comment: how come it works on SQL server not on Oracle?!!..Any restrictions in Oracle for Two level aggregations?

Comment: @Raju . . . I didn't say it wouldn't work with two levels of aggregations, just that this version is simpler and more portable.

Comment: If thats the case why it was throwing error for my query. Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: @Raju . . . The query in your question is Oracle syntax and would not work in SQL Server.  If you have a question about SQL Server, then ask *another* question, and include the appropriate query, sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your error `ORA-00904: ColumnName : invalid identifier`

If you use quoted aliases for columns "Tots", "CRIR", "RT", "Succes" in subquery, then you need use the same quoted aliases in main query.

Quoted aliases are case sensitive. But nonquoted aliases are not case sensitive. Oracle interprets them as uppercase.

It will be work:

```
select sum("Tots"),sum("CRIR"),sum("RT"),sum("Succes") from( 

select  ds.LOAN_ID,ds.CUST_ID,TO_CHAR(ds.SENT_DT_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "Dates", count(*) "Tots", 
  SUM(DECODE (ds.STATUS, 'CR', 1,'IR',1,0)) "CRIR",
  SUM(DECODE (ds.STATUS, 'R', 1,'T',1,0)) "RT",
  SUM(DECODE (ds.STATUS, 'S', 1, 0)) "Succes"
  FROM DATA_STRING ds
  WHERE TRUNC(ds.SENT_DT_TIME) BETWEEN to_date('2016-10-04','yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2016-10-07','yyyy-mm-dd')
  Group by ds.LOAN_ID,ds.CUST_ID,TO_CHAR(ds.SENT_DT_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
);
```